# C# object connection with dynamic labels in dynamic objects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, connection

I have created a dynamic form, and inside it dynamic objects. But for some reason when i create dynamic event handlers, the event handlers don't pick up the dynamic objects. That is, they don't appear on the dropdown list of options in Visual Studios.

The code:

```
private void btnShop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form frmShop = new Form();
        frmShop.Show();

        Button newButton = new Button();
        Button Add = new Button();
        Label Meat = new Label();
        Label Carrots = new Label();
        Label DogFood = new Label();
        Label Fish = new Label();
        Label Rainbows = new Label();

        frmShop.Controls.Add(Meat);
        frmShop.Controls.Add(Carrots);
        frmShop.Controls.Add(DogFood);
        frmShop.Controls.Add(Fish);
        frmShop.Controls.Add(Rainbows);

        frmShop.Controls.Add(newButton);
        frmShop.Controls.Add(Add);

        frmShop.Size = new Size(300,300);

        //HERE IS MY PROBLEM v //
        frmShop.Controls.Add(lblCount) 
    }
```

Comment: what is `lblCount` and what issue are you having? Do you get an error or something?

Comment: The variable _Rainbow_ is local to the btnShop_Click and you cannot use its name hoping that you can reference the methods and properties of the label. You need to move your controls to a global scope or give them an name and retrieve them from the form controls collection

Comment: @CodingYoshi  sorry, edited it again. Basically, the label Rainbows's text has to change when the dynamically created button is clicked. but the Rainbows label doesnt show up when i start typing Rainbows in the place where i've shown i want it. and when i fully type it it just gives me the error "The name 'Rainbows' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @Steve yes! Im pretty noob at coding, how do i fix that? How do i move it to a global scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable Rainbow is local to the *btnShop_Click* event handler and you cannot use this variable in another method even if you use the same name.  [Learn about scoping here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)

You need to move your controls to a global scope or give them an name and retrieve them from the form controls collection.

For example, move the variable receiving your dynamic form to a global scope (outside any class method but inside the class declaration)

```
private Form frmShop = null;

private void btnShop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmShow = new Form();
    .....

    // Set the Name property for the label
    Label Rainbow = new Label { Name = "Rainbow" }
    ...

    frmShow.Controls.Add(Rainbow);


}

protected void newButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...

    // Try to extract the label required from the form controls collection
    // using the specified name
    Label aRainbowLabel = frmShow.Controls
                                 .OfType<Label>()
                                 .FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name=="Rainbow");
    aRainbowLabel.Text = "Rainbows: 1";
}
```

Beware that you are following a dangerous path here. The variable frmShow is global and if you click again the same button you will create a second form with the same elements. If this is allright then no problem, but if you want only one form of this kind you need to check the variable for null before creating the form and set the variable frmShow back to null if you close that form.